# android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): The camera device has been disconnected

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-camera

I've been struggling for a bit with Android Camera2 APIs.
When I rotate my device I'm getting

```
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): checkPidStatus:1795: The camera device has been disconnected
```

During debugging I found out that it happens on this part of code

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
```

and than goes to catch section which handle CameraAccessException. Sometimes background is getting white and I cannot see camera preview. Here is a part of code:

```
    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull final CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        createCameraPreviewSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull final CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull final CameraDevice cameraDevice, final int error) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null != activity) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }
};

private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
        final SurfaceTexture texture = mAutoFitTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;

        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        final Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder
                = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface),
                getStateCallback(), null
        );
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("CameraAccessException: createCameraPreviewSession()", e.toString());
    }
}

@NonNull
private CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback getStateCallback() {
    return new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onReady(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            super.onReady(session);
            Log.d("getStateCallback: onReady()", "");
        }


        @Override
        public void onClosed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            super.onClosed(session);
            Log.d("getStateCallback: onClosed()", "");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigured(@NonNull final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }

            mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;

            try {
                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

                mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                        mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
            } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("CameraAccessException: onConfigured()", e.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(
                @NonNull final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
            Log.d("getStateCallback: onConfigureFailed()", "failed");
            showToast();
        }
    };
}

private void openCamera(final int width, final int height) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestCameraPermission();
        return;
    }
    setUpCameraOutputs(width, height);
    configureTransform(width, height);
    final CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        Objects.requireNonNull(manager).openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("CameraAccessException: openCamera()", e.toString());
    }
    initAROverlayView();
}

@MainThread
private void closeCamera() {
    try {
        try {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("InterruptedException", e.toString());
        }
        if (null != mCaptureSession) {
            mCaptureSession.close();
            mCaptureSession = null;
        }
        if (null != mCameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    } finally {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startBackgroundThread();
    registerSensors();
    if (mAutoFitTextureView.isAvailable()) {
        openCamera(mAutoFitTextureView.getWidth(), mAutoFitTextureView.getHeight());
    } else {
        mAutoFitTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    try {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("InterruptedException", e.toString());
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find the origin of this problem? Thanks.